# The $directory variable doesn't contain the correct value

Tags: 7, theming

When I print the content of `$directory` in my theme's page--front.tpl.php, it outputs "modules/system."

This is not I want; I want to output "sites/all/mytheme/images/…." How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to find the folder of your theme you have to use something like this:

```
<?php echo drupal_get_path('theme','your_theme').'/images/whateverfile.ext'; ?>
```

Comment: you're right. thank you. but why echo $directory can't output the theme directory in page--front.tpl.php? but can in page.tpl.php.

Comment: the `$directory` variable is done in [template_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7) which uses the [path_to_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) function. so there is your answer.